# Epson WF-3730 not installed since upgrading to Kubuntu 23.04 from 22.10

Tags: drivers, printing

I recently upgrade from Kubuntu 22.10 to 23.04. I am having issues, but the most important is my printer is no longer installed. I installed it years ago in 20.04 and upgrading to 22.10 it was still there and printed/scanned fine. Today I went to change the tray from main to alternate and it was not available to change. Always before it had given me options to use printer settings where I could select the paper tray, but today only properties is available under the printer name (which is correct) and most items are greyed out, cannot be changed. So I went into settings and system reports no printer installed. I tried to add printer, but after selecting network, Epson WF-3730 showed up and asked for ip address and "queue" which I do not understand queue info. I input ip address and all boxes including finish were greyed out.

I have checked that cups is running and in terminal:

`avahi-browse --all -t -r`:

```
 wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscans._tcp         local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscans._tcp         local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscan._tcp          local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscan._tcp          local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _privet._tcp         local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _privet._tcp         local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Secure Internet Printer local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Secure Internet Printer local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Internet Printer     local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Internet Printer     local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _scanner._tcp        local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _scanner._tcp        local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Microsoft Windows Network local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Microsoft Windows Network local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Web Site             local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Web Site             local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          PDL Printer          local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          PDL Printer          local
+   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          UNIX Printer         local
+   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          UNIX Printer         local
+   wlo1 IPv4 amzn.dmgr:F82B5E3EE4B8DA964153EA96282355CC:xnVDMM+4u1:209679 Amazon Fire TV       local
+   wlo1 IPv4 aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMTMyLjEwOTo2OTQy          _cider-remote._tcp   local
+   wlo1 IPv4 3.27.0.112-CYBERTRONPC.cd90725e-7149-4ee3-9287-15c007754c0c _nvstream_dbd._tcp   local
+   wlo1 IPv4 3.27.0.112-MYVIOLINSINGS.36772945-12da-4f43-beaa-10cb07baf4e6 _nvstream_dbd._tcp   local
=   wlo1 IPv4 amzn.dmgr:F82B5E3EE4B8DA964153EA96282355CC:xnVDMM+4u1:209679 Amazon Fire TV       local
   hostname = [192-168-132-30.local]
   address = [192.168.132.30]
   port = [36672]
   txt = ["f=0" "c=0a:7c:39:1b:7e:2b" "t=2" "dpv=1" "ad=AKPGW064GI9HE" "a=0" "u=F82B5E3EE4B8DA964153EA96282355CC" "v=2" "mv=2" "pv=1" "sp=34225" "n=sheila's Fire TV" "tr=tcp" "at=WItvDk6atLJ9" "s=0"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMTMyLjEwOTo2OTQy          _cider-remote._tcp   local
   hostname = [aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMTMyLjEwOTo2OTQy.local]
   address = [192.168.132.109]
   port = [3839]
   txt = ["iV=196623" "CtlN=Cider" "txtvers=1" "OSsi=0x212F0" "DvTy=Cider" "DbId=D41D8CD98F00B205" "DvSv=3689" "Ver=131077"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 3.27.0.112-CYBERTRONPC.cd90725e-7149-4ee3-9287-15c007754c0c _nvstream_dbd._tcp   local
   hostname = [CybertronPC.local]
   address = [192.168.132.106]
   port = [47989]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv4 3.27.0.112-MYVIOLINSINGS.36772945-12da-4f43-beaa-10cb07baf4e6 _nvstream_dbd._tcp   local
   hostname = [myviolinsings.local]
   address = [192.168.132.31]
   port = [47989]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          UNIX Printer         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [515]
   txt = ["note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "qtotal=1" "rp=auto" "pdl=raw" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "priority=50" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          PDL Printer          local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [9100]
   txt = ["note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "qtotal=1" "pdl=raw" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "priority=40" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Web Site             local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [80]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Microsoft Windows Network local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [445]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _scanner._tcp        local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [1865]
   txt = ["note=" "scannerAvailable=1" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "mdl=WF-3730 Series" "mfg=EPSON" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Internet Printer     local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["TLS=1.2" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "priority=30" "mopria-certified=1.3" "URF=CP1,PQ4-5,OB9,OFU0,RS300-600,SRGB24,W8,DM3,IS1-2,V1.4,MT1-3-6-8-10-11-12" "PaperMax=legal-A4" "kind=document,envelope,photo" "rfo=ipp/faxout" "Fax=T" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "qtotal=1" "rp=ipp/print" "pdl=application/octet-stream,image/pwg-raster,image/urf,image/jpeg" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          UNIX Printer         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [515]
   txt = ["note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "qtotal=1" "rp=auto" "pdl=raw" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "priority=50" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          PDL Printer          local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [9100]
   txt = ["note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "qtotal=1" "pdl=raw" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "priority=40" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Web Site             local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [80]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Microsoft Windows Network local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [445]
   txt = []
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _scanner._tcp        local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [1865]
   txt = ["note=" "scannerAvailable=1" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "mdl=WF-3730 Series" "mfg=EPSON" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Internet Printer     local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["TLS=1.2" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "priority=30" "mopria-certified=1.3" "URF=CP1,PQ4-5,OB9,OFU0,RS300-600,SRGB24,W8,DM3,IS1-2,V1.4,MT1-3-6-8-10-11-12" "PaperMax=legal-A4" "kind=document,envelope,photo" "rfo=ipp/faxout" "Fax=T" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "qtotal=1" "rp=ipp/print" "pdl=application/octet-stream,image/pwg-raster,image/urf,image/jpeg" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Secure Internet Printer local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["TLS=1.2" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "priority=30" "mopria-certified=1.3" "URF=CP1,PQ4-5,OB9,OFU0,RS300-600,SRGB24,W8,DM3,IS1-2,V1.4,MT1-3-6-8-10-11-12" "PaperMax=legal-A4" "kind=document,envelope,photo" "rfo=ipp/faxout" "Fax=T" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "qtotal=1" "rp=ipp/print" "pdl=application/octet-stream,image/pwg-raster,image/urf,image/jpeg" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _privet._tcp         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [80]
   txt = ["cs=online" "id=" "type=printer" "url=https://www.google.com/cloudprint" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series (EPSONC8ECE1)" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscan._tcp          local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [443]
   txt = ["representation=https://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:443/PRESENTATION/AIRPRINT/PRINTER_128.PNG" "note=" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "duplex=F" "is=platen,adf" "cs=color,grayscale,binary" "pdl=application/pdf,image/jpeg" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "rs=eSCL" "vers=2.62" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv6 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscans._tcp         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [443]
   txt = ["representation=https://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:443/PRESENTATION/AIRPRINT/PRINTER_128.PNG" "note=" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "duplex=F" "is=platen,adf" "cs=color,grayscale,binary" "pdl=application/pdf,image/jpeg" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "rs=eSCL" "vers=2.62" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          Secure Internet Printer local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["TLS=1.2" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "note=" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "priority=30" "mopria-certified=1.3" "URF=CP1,PQ4-5,OB9,OFU0,RS300-600,SRGB24,W8,DM3,IS1-2,V1.4,MT1-3-6-8-10-11-12" "PaperMax=legal-A4" "kind=document,envelope,photo" "rfo=ipp/faxout" "Fax=T" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "qtotal=1" "rp=ipp/print" "pdl=application/octet-stream,image/pwg-raster,image/urf,image/jpeg" "product=(EPSON WF-3730 Series)" "usb_MDL=WF-3730 Series" "usb_MFG=EPSON" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _privet._tcp         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [80]
   txt = ["cs=online" "id=" "type=printer" "url=https://www.google.com/cloudprint" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series (EPSONC8ECE1)" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscan._tcp          local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [443]
   txt = ["representation=https://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:443/PRESENTATION/AIRPRINT/PRINTER_128.PNG" "note=" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "duplex=F" "is=platen,adf" "cs=color,grayscale,binary" "pdl=application/pdf,image/jpeg" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "rs=eSCL" "vers=2.62" "txtvers=1"]
=   wlo1 IPv4 EPSON WF-3730 Series                          _uscans._tcp         local
   hostname = [EPSONC8ECE1.local]
   address = [192.168.132.148]
   port = [443]
   txt = ["representation=https://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:443/PRESENTATION/AIRPRINT/PRINTER_128.PNG" "note=" "UUID=cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-9caed3c8ece1" "adminurl=http://EPSONC8ECE1.local.:80/PRESENTATION/BONJOUR" "duplex=F" "is=platen,adf" "cs=color,grayscale,binary" "pdl=application/pdf,image/jpeg" "ty=EPSON WF-3730 Series" "rs=eSCL" "vers=2.62" "txtvers=1"]
```

As indicated, this is a network printer in my home office with several computers able to print to it. And I am able to print, just have no controls for changing the trays which have different paper types for printing business docs.

If you need more info, please advise as I am stumped.